# Is there a differential equation describing the wavefunction of a hadron?

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-chromodynamics, differential-equations, hadron-dynamics

In Newtonian Physics there's a differential equation describing the motion of multiple bodies in orbit around each other.  In non relativistic quantum mechanics there's a differential equation describing the wavefunction of electrons in an atom.

In the case of a hadron relativistic quantum mechanics is needed to describe the interaction between the quarks.  Also the quarks in one hadron don't interact with the quarks in another hadron through the color interaction but instead hadrons interact with each other by exchanging mesons.

I was wondering if there's a differential equation describing the wavefunction of a hadron.

Comment: Google a "shell model of nucleus".

Answer (score 1):

The Schrödinger equation describes hadrons in the non-relativistic limit. If spin interactions are relevant, the Pauli equation with its magnetic spin interaction will do the job. The Klein-Gordon equation describes hadrons with the non-relativistic restriction, however again only if spin is not important. If spin is important then you need the so-called squared Dirac equation with the appropriate gyromagnetic ratio put in by hand. The Dirac equation only applies to leptons.

Note that I assumed only electromagnetic interaction takes place. If you include other interactions things are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A wave function of a hadron just tells you about the state of a hadron, something like how many partons in that state, and what their properties (quantum numbers, momenta) are. However I don't think it can tell you the internal interactions between partons: they are described by the Lagrangian of the corresponding theory.

There is a quantity quite close to the above sense of wave function: parton distribution function (PDF). Its evolution in the resolution scale is ruled by the DGLAP equation, which behaves as a renormalization group equation. The extensions of the PDF concept include TMD (transverse momentum distribution) and GPD (Generalized Parton Distribution), which are of interest of many studies now.